# Domain Masking and Path Forwarding

Tags: php, html, web

I need to direct my domain www.abc.com to www.xyz.com/folder/form/ and pass parameters to the form, but I need to mask the path so that when users go to www.xyz.com that's all they see along with any passed parameters in the url. Is the possible? How can I achieve this?

I do not own both domains. I own www.abc.com and the folder in www.xyz.com, but not the naked domain. The domains are on different servers.

I have tried the solution setting the DNS to *.abc.com and the CNAME to www and www.xyz.com. But, CNAME's do not allow pointing to a path. If I do a 301 or 302 forward the domain is not masked. What else can I do. I've been pouring over this for days.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How, depends on your setup. Start by doing some research and try something. If you then run into some specific issue with your attempt, come back, show us what you've tried, where/how it goes wrong and explain your setup (if the sites are on the same/different server etc).

Comment: I have tried the solution setting the DNS to *.abc.com and the CNAME to www and www.xyz.com. But, CNAME's do not allow pointing to a path. If I do a 301 or 302 forward the domain is not masked. What else can I do. I've been pouring over this for days.

Comment: Do you own both domains? Are they on the same server? What is it your trying to solve with this solution (just to see if there's some other solution)?

Comment: I do not own both domains. I own www.abc.com and the folder in www.xyz.com, but not the naked domain. The domains are on different servers.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "proxy" here, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to achieve url masking without using DNS setting.

**On server level:** Setting up reverse proxy.

If you are using apache, you can use the module named [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Once you have enabled the module, Add following to your `.htaccess` which is in your `abc` domain root.

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/folder/form/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/folder/form/
```

**Another way** to achieve similar result would be, as follows which does pretty much same thing under the hood.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/folder/form/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

**On language level**: Using a scripting language like `php` and then pipe the data to and fro via. the second domain using `curl`. Kinda mix of 'man in the middle attack" and "phishing". But most importantly, it's pretty much possible.

Then we have other run of the mill solutions like using `<iframe>`. etc.